# Javascript - Optimal way to update properties of some items in array

Tags: javascript, list, optimization, arrow-functions

```
let list = [ 
 { name: "a", position: 10 },
 { name: "b", position: 71 },
 { name: "c", position: 2 },     
 { name: "d", position: 34 },
 { name: "e", position: 1 },
 { name: "f", position: 0 }
]
```

Update all the items, position greater than 2, increase their position by 1.

I went by this code but I fear this would be very slow for lists with thousands of members:

```
    list.forEach(i => {
        if (i.position > 2) {
            i.position ++;
        }            
    });
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, so please help me out.

Comment: Nope that's pretty much it. If you want to affect each object in a list of objects, you generally don't have a choice but to visit and operate upon each one of them.

Comment: I hoped for some magic with .map?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) - do you actually have a performance issue with the presented code? Order-wise it's as good as it gets, and while it can surely be optimized a bit, the before mentioned is what you should ask yourself.

Comment: @Pointy, that's not pretty much it. That loop is crazy. You can use a regular `for` loop so you start at the increment, and `break;`  out of  the loop, therefore saving iterations... or just use the `.slice` or `.splice` *(depending on needs)* you need.

Comment: @Dalibor `.map()` is best used when transforming *every* element of an array, and often when wanting to keep the original array around, since it isn't mutated. In this case, it really wouldn't be used much differently than your current loop.

Comment: @StackSlave don't be misguided by position in example it's 0, 1, 2... but in real world it's 12, 76, 4... so I don't know how would `for` help me instead of `forEach`. I'll update the question to avoid confusion

Comment: @StackSlave the OP just wants to skip the first **two** positions. There's really no point in "optimizing" something like this; it's an inherently linear operation, and one method of "looping" is as good as another. If it's a performance problem, the issue is probably with the data structure itself and not the loop implementation.

Comment: Methods like `.forEach()` and `.map()` are also loops. Those two in particular are very similar, the difference being that `.map()` is for creating a *new* array from an existing array. Otherwise, they're both internally-driven linear passes over an array, not significantly different from what a plain indexed `for` loop will do.

Comment: @Dalibor, what do you mean by "optimizing"? I think you might want to use a [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: @Dalibor Is `i.position ++;` just an example? Is the real operation more costly than this? Or is this it?

Comment: @zcoop98  This is it, the code is litteraly like this (of course, 2 in condition is dynamic, I used value 2 just for the sake of example), positions are increased by 1, and the list could be huge, thousands of items.

Comment: @Dalibor This is a way to do it with map if you must but as was pointed out before there is no need to and acutally the map might run slower than the forEach loop   

`var updatedList = list.map(obj => {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj["name"] = obj.name;
    newObj["position"] = (obj.position > 2)?obj.position+1:obj.position;
    return newObj;
   });`

Comment: Because we seem to want to endulge in premature optimization: `const t = ((x + 1) & -4); x += ((t | ~t + 1) >>> 31) & 1` (`x` is `position`) should be branch-less code for the increment with condition of being `2`. You should then unroll a standard for loop, which doesn't fit into a comment, but it's pretty straight forward. Then you'll finally have it - unreadable code, that solves a problem that never existed in the first place.

Comment: @mikesp Why didn't you post it as answer? It's a bit hard to read and analyze like this...

Comment: @Dalibor: I didn't think it would solve the problem, just posted to illustrate how you could do it. Just add a break after each ; and you should be good

Comment: If you use `setInverval` and `clearInterval` you won't have an issue with the loop killing the page.

Comment: If you had a linked list you could add an entry after the second, and would automatically "shift" the position of all following entries. On the other hand that would mean that for every node in the linked list you'd have to count it's position on access. So if performance is a thing, this has to be analyzed in a larger context.

Comment: @ASDFGerte On the other hand a condition that is only false three times and is true for all other elements is probably no problem for branch prediction, so replacing the branch with some extra bitshifting might not actually be faster (though it is a valid idea)

Comment: He is checking `position`, which is not the index. No distribution of how often that should be above two was given. Also, if we are not so strict, and go away from a javascript array, we could peek at things like [wasm simd 128](https://v8.dev/features/simd), other vector operations, shaders, ..., and i am not really serious, i sometimes end up just throwing things into discussions, which have some truth in their code, but rather want to express "do you really want to go down that path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have an optimization issue here, especially when the operation you're doing to each element is so trivial and quick to do. Per [@ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte) in [their comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430873/javascript-optimal-way-to-update-properties-of-some-items-in-array#comment117442193_66430873), you can even create a branch-less version.

I threw together an example, where I create an array of 1 million objects and then send it through the `forEach` you've provided, and it takes only 15-30 ms per run:

```js
function test() {
  let arr = [];

  //Populate array with 1 million objects with pos. from 0-99
  for (i = 1000000; i > 0; i--)
    arr[i] = {
      name: i.toString(),
      position: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100))
    };

  let start = performance.now(); //Record start time

  arr.forEach(i => { //Exact loop from question
    if (i.position > 2) {
      i.position++;
    }
  });

  let end = performance.now(); //Record end time
  console.log('Time to Execute:', end - start, 'ms');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Execute</button>
```

If your quantity is on the level of "thousands" like you've mentioned, then you can stop right here and sleep easy with what you've got, because that's probably plenty fast enough for your use.

However, if you've got quantities even larger than this, say 10's or 100's of millions, then you may need to look into something called [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) in order to split the task off into chunks to run concurrently.

You could split your list into pieces smaller than some threshold (eg., 1 million), and have the workers process those pieces at the same time so that your total time used would only be as long as the slowest group. This wouldn't be about optimizing your loop logic anymore though.

Comment: Thanks. performance.now() - that is new to me, I've always measured performance with Date.now()

Answer (score 0):

It won't be slow, but your code is a bit verbose. I would go for a simple `.map()`:

```js
list = list.map(
    item => item.position <= 2 ? item : {...item, position: item.position + 1}
);
```

Don't bother with micro-optimization, go for a readable code instead if it's fast enough.

Comment: `.map()` will build a new array instead of simply modifying the content of the original array.

Comment: I agree with @Pointy, if speed is actually an issue for OP, then there's no reason to add in the extra overhead of creating a new array instead of just sticking with `forEach` or a manual `for` loop.

Comment: @Pointy so? These array methods are optimized enough to run super fast. Unless it's like a million of elements, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @RoboRobok oh I definitely agree, and if there are millions of elements, the problem is the data structure itself, and not the loop.

Comment: @Pointy - just curious, why would the data structure be the problem? Imagine "name" is unique index. How would you optimize this data, if you expect millions of elements?

Comment: I disagree with "verbose". I think the OP's solution is actually cleaner than this `.map`. Anyways, wether a certain code is cleaner or not is not quite on-topic here.

Comment: @Dalibor if you have a large amount of data that needs to be accessed in certain patterns - finding by index, or key, or grouped, or whatever - then the most important optimization is finding a data structure that facilitates those tasks such that the amount of work necessary is minimized. That's basically what Computer Science is all about.

Comment: @JonasWilms I think it's only cleaner, because we don't have it in context here. In real life, the data array will be used in separate place and we will need the updated one in our expression. For loops are almost never clean solutions in real life programming.